# Can't find error in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I can't fint the error in this code? Preciate some help! I also wonder how put values into this stored procedure from PHP/SQL

```
"
-- SP create new article
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS {$spCreateArticle};

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE {$spCreateArticle}
(
IN articleUserId INT,
IN articleSubject CHAR(50),
IN articleText TEXT,
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO {$tableArticle}
(articleUserId, articleSubject, articleText, articleDate)
VALUES
(spArticleUserId, spArticleSubject, spArticleText, NOW());

END //
DELIMITER ;
",
```

Error message:
Error code 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE PCreateArticle ( IN articleUserId INT, IN arti' at line 4)

Comment: So, what's the error you are getting? Might it have something to do with the comma after `articleText TEXT`?

Comment: I added the error message above. Removed the comma, but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Should `IN articleUserId INT` etc. instead be `IN spArticleUserId INT` etc?

Comment: Hmmm, didn't help! I totaly new in stored procedures!